# Custom HashSet Class

Tags: java, collections

I want create custom HashSet class in java, The class contain all override method of Hashset Class Those behavior as per my requirement.
Is it possible?

```
class MyCustomHashSet<String> extends HashSet<String>{
    @Override
    public boolean add(String e) {

        return super.add(e);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {

        return super.contains(o);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


        Set<String> set = new MyCustomHashSet<String>();
        set.add("Abc");
        set.add("abc");

    System.out.println("Size---"+set.size());
    System.out.println(set);

    }
```

In main method i am going to add 2 same string but contains is different upper case lower case and i want only one result which i add first .....

Comment: You could just try it...

Comment: @BackSlash But how?????  ihave try it in my custom class but i can't add value in map which use by HashSet class at that point i have stop.....:(

Comment: A good starting point would be to post the code you tried, explaining what doesn't work, why, what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: Try changing `MyCustomHashSet<String>` to `MyCustomHashSet`. You might be hiding `java.util.String` with your type parameter `String`

Comment: Use `class MyCustomHashSet extends HashSet<String>`. By declaring a class like `class MyCustomHashSet<String>` you are creating a **type parameter named “String”** which hides the real type `String`. Note that implementing such a `Map` via subclassing is strongly discouraged. Use *delegation* instead.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you are trying to make HashSet case-insensitive, that means that if I add `"Abc"` and then `"abc"`, it should only keep `"Abc"`.

As user3580294 pointed out in comments, you should name your set `MyCustomHashSet` instead of `MyCustomHashSet<String>`.

You could then override the `add(String)` method to check for your string to be in the set, something like:

```
@Override
public boolean add(String e) {
    for(String current : this) {
        if(e.equalsIgnoreCase(current)) {
            return false; //if string is already in the set, we don't add it.
        }
    }
    return super.add(e);
}
```

You can see a live working example [here](http://ideone.com/srIizP).

Comment: Thanks for your ans by this way i have find my problem and create Custom HashSet class which is generic as Type level.....

Comment: It's not generic... Your class extends `HashSet<String>` which is a  `HashSet` of `String`s

Comment: You could also use a `TreeSet` providing the desired comparator. `Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`